# Evanescent waves in material with negative refractive index $n$

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction

When $n<0$ an evanescent wave will exponentially  grow. It means that in the evanescent region the energy density can be very high.

Is it correct that if I have a large slab of a such material the wave may take a long time to get reflected because first the wave has to deposit the energy in the evanescent  region.

Does it lead in reality to a high absorption /ohmic losses?

**appendix:** materials with negative refractive index doesn't occur naturally. They have to be created artificiality. These materials are called "*meta-materials*" and posses many counterintuitive properties such as growths of evanescent  waves.

It is a hot research topic. The application are superlenses ,  invisibility cloak to name just few.

Comment: I'm not sure what an "evanescent" wave in a $n<0$ material really means. Where would the energy come from?

Comment: @ptomato evanescent  wave doesn't carry energy.  So the energy conservation  law is not violated.

Comment: It matters if the material is thin and the wave leaks out the other side, like in FTIR.